# onclick doesn't work properly after append

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I am creating unordered list items on the fly. Each of which contains a text and an anchor tag (red cross sign). Now what I want is that on clicking the anchor tag it prints the child number of the list item it's in. I want this without reloading the page.

```
 if (status === 'success') {
     const i = document.createElement("i");
     i.classList.add("fa");
     i.classList.add("fa-times");
     i.classList.add('red-cross');

     const a = document.createElement("a");
     a.classList.add("ml-4");
     a.append(i);

     const t = document.createTextNode(txt)

     const newItem = document.createElement("li");
     newItem.append(t);
     newItem.append(a);

     $("ul#"+list).append(newItem).on('click', 'li a', function() {
         const cnt =  $("ul#"+list).children().length;
         console.log(cnt);
     }); }
```

View:
[Unordered list of items with text and cross sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6u9j.png)

Expected output:
On clicking i'th cross sign, the output should be i.

Current output:
The output is always 6 regardless which number cross I click.

Comment: Do you declare `list` using `var` keyword?

Comment: @GrantHerman It wouldn't. The const is isolated to each callback scope.

Answer (score 1):

The click function is not run until you have clicked on the link. So the `const cnt =  $("ul#"+list).children().length;` will not be calculated until you click, and I guess all your items has been added at that point hence the result of 6 for all of them.

To use that method you have to invoke the calculation when the function is created as this:

```
$("ul#"+list).append(newItem).on('click', 'li a', (function() {
    const cnt =  $("ul#"+list).children().length;

    return function () {
        console.log(cnt);
    }
}()));
```

This is not a good solution however since you add a new event listener for each item added. You are probably better of with something like:

```
var list = $("ul#test");
list.on('click', 'li a', function () {
    var idx = list.children().index($(this).closest('li'));
  console.log(idx);
});
```

That has to be done only once, then add the new items with just:

```
$("ul#test").append(newItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Expected output: On clicking i'th cross sign output shoud be i.
>
> Current output: The output is always 6 regardless which number cross I click.

If clicking *i*-th `li` should output *i* (the index of the `li`) of *n* (the total number of `li`) then you should do something like

```
const children =  $("ul#"+list + " li a").children();
const i = children.index(this) + 1 // +1 to count from 1
console.log(i);
```

This checks at which position the clicked a is at - and since you only have one `<i>` for each `<a>` the count is the same.